# How to reduce this below java code?

Tags: java, android

Here I've written some code to navigate to different links using different buttons in android. Is there anyway to reduce my code further than I've coded. If it is possible please do help me to reduce the code. here is my code:

```
Button tv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my1);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(myscale);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("link1"));
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Exception Caught", e.toString());
                    }

                }
            }, 50);

        }
    });

    Button tv1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my2);
    tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(myscale);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("link2"));
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Exception Caught", e.toString());
                    }

                }
            }, 50);

        }
    });
    Button tv2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my3);
    tv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(myscale);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("link3"));
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Exception Caught", e.toString());
                    }

                }
            }, 50);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Since you're doing the exact same thing to three different `Button`s, why not write a method that takes a `Button` argument and call it three times?

Comment: Sorry I've to display 3 buttons and they should navigate to three different links

Comment: Then you shouldn't have put the same link in your code example (OK, thanks for editing it).  Anyway, all that means is that you add another argument to your method to pass the link.

Comment: Can you please show me the example @ajb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one method for click listener and use if condition.

Here is sample code.

**Your OnCreate Code:**

```
Button tv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my1);
onClick(tv);

tv1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my2);
onClick(tv1);

Button tv2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my3);
onClick(tv2);
```

**Common Method :** Declare `mLink` Variable as Global

```
public void onClick(View v)
    {
        v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v == tv)
                    mLink = "link1";
                else if(v == tv1)
                    mLink = "link2";
                else if(v == tv2)
                    mLink = "link3";

                v.startAnimation(myscale);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(mLink));
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Exception Caught", e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }, 50);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Once try as follows take a method for re usability

```
public void openLink(final String link){
 v.startAnimation(myscale);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse(link));
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exception Caught", e.toString());
                }

            }
        }, 50);
}
```

and implements **onClickListener** and in **onClick**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    super.onClick(v);
    switch (v.getId()) {    
    case R.id.my1:
       openLink(link1);
        break;
    case R.id.my2:
        openLink(link2);
        break;
   case R.id.my3:
          openLink(link3);
        break;
    }
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Button tv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my1);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startAnotherActivity("link1");
        }
    });

    Button tv1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my2);
    tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startAnotherActivity("link2");
        }
    });
    Button tv2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my3);
    tv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startAnotherActivity("link3");

        }
    });

    private void startAnotherActivity(final String link){
        v.startAnimation(myscale);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse(link));
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exception Caught", e.toString());
                }

            }
        }, 50);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

implement onClickListener on your activity and override the onClick() method and write your code in this manner

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        super.onClick(v);
        switch (v.getId()) {    
        case R.id.my1:
            //your code here
            break;
        case R.id.my2:
            //your code here
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll post an example, but only because there's a little non-trivial concept that needs explaining:

```
Button tv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my1);
setListenerForButton(tv, "link1");
Button tv1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my2);
setListenerForButton(tv1, "link2");
Button tv2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my3);
setListenerForButton(tv1, "link3");



private void setListenerForButton(Button button, final String link) {
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(myscale);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse(link));
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Exception Caught", e.toString());
                    }

                }
            }, 50);

        }
    });
}
```

The detail is that for `link` to be used in the anonymous inner class that you're setting up for the listener, `link` has to be `final`.

I've looked this over and believe it will work, but I haven't tried it.